# MY SQL. Error 1292: Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value

Tags: mysql

Tengo que borrar un registro duplicado de una tabla pero por mas que intento todas las sugerencias que a otros le han servido, sigo sin poder evadirme del error 1292.
Agradeceré si pueden orientarme donde puede estar el error.
El número de pedido es el duplicado y el id de pedido es lo que uso como filtro para eliminar el que quiero.
Ya intenté reemplazando el AND por coma y tampoco sirvió. Muchas gracias!

```
SELECT *
FROM datoscrudos.raw_pedidos_wocommerce
WHERE numero_de_pedido = 41624;

set sql_safe_updates=0;
DELETE
FROM datoscrudos.raw_pedidos_wocommerce
WHERE numero_de_pedido = 41624 and 'id cliente' = 1324;
```

Comment: 1. ¿De verdad el campo se llama `id cliente` o es `id_cliente`? 2. Si querés "encerrar" tus campos, debés usar acentos graves (`), no comillas simples (').

Comment: 1.El campo se llama id cliente 2. Cambio las comillas por los acentos y sigue dando error